# bytea barfs when set to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design

I am saving binary data to the database for in-process imaging so i can progressively operate on the image without having to round trip it to my data store.  In order to keep the database size manageable, I only allow each user to have one image active at a time, so I set all the image fields to nil except the active one, so the user has lots of jobs with image data pointers, but only one with actual image data.

When I set the field to nil, i get the colorful error message
[wtf]

```
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `bytesize' for nil:NilClass
```

If i set the field to '' things are happy.  Am I misunderstanding the use of nil in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It means you've a (validation?) check somewhere in ruby that is computing the size of the binary string using bytesize. It should conditionally do so when the string is not nil instead.